# NSMutableArray sorting

Tags: objective-c, ios, sorting, uitableview, nsmutablearray

[image]

I have 5 NSMutableArrays in cell. I need to sort cells by one value.
Example I need to sort cell by time.

```
[MyArray1 sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

but how I will be with other 4 NSMutableArray in cell?

Comment: you should upload your image directly to stackoverflow, there's all sorts of junk on that "sharing" site

Comment: He has not enough reputation to do so

Comment: i upload, but i can't doing the post, my reputation 1

Comment: Please search for it. This question has been answered before.

Comment: The least confusing approach for a beginner is to use sortUsingFunction and write a function that knows how to locate and compare the two items you want compared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a good idea to store data for your cells in 5 arrays, don't separate them; create a data container class, store all values for each cell inside one data container object and then you can sort your array with data containers by one of the values.

e.g.:

DataContainer.h:

```
@interface DataContainer : NSObject
{
    NSDate *date1;
    NSDate *date2;
    NSString *upperTitle;
    NSString *mainTitle;
    NSString *subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *upperTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mainTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```

DataContainer.m:

```
@implementation DataContainer
@synthesize date1, date2, upperTitle, mainTitle, subtitle;
@end
```

Then you can create your `DataContainer`'s (one for each cell) and store them in **one** `NSMutableArray`.

e.g.:

```
DataContainer *container = [[DataContainer alloc] init];
[container setDate1:[NSDate date]];
[container setMainTitle:@"blahblah"];
///...
[cellArr addObject:container];
```

To sort this array, use:

```
cellArr = [cellArr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id cont1, id cont2) {
                return [[(DataContainer *) cont1 date1] compare:[(DataContainer *) cont2 date1]];
            }];
```

and then use them in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
DataContainer *container = [cellArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//container.date1, container.date2, container.upperTitle, container.mainTitle and container.subtitle are the values that you need for your cell.
```

Notice that this code is suitable if you're using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) for your project; if you're not using ARC, then you need to change `strong` to `retain` in property definitions and add `release`'s to needed places to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: but can I sort cell if I have example, MyArray1, MyArray2, MyArray3, MyArray4, MyArray5 in cell?

Comment: Why do you need these five arrays? It's a pretty bad way to present data in `UITableViewCell`'s.

Comment: if I will be edit my code and doing class with data it will be very long

Comment: It will take no more than one hour. Anyway, you can't do what you want with your current architecture, so you have to refactor your code.

Comment: can you help me, how right create data container and then establish value to cell;
example
cell1=...
cell2=...
cell3=...
cell4=...
cell5=...
I have got 6 section and in section is 5 value;
how right doing container?

Comment: thanks. I doing a new class about as you;
i have got a class lesson
http://i27.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0128/75/b3f35048760eeef0f6dfef10fe9e9e75.png
i have got a class Week
http://i31.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0128/98/c3ed55c410fc62b78df122d5a9960898.png
i add elements
http://i29.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0128/ec/d9ae1bb6c16c408fd014fea64ac6f8ec.png
but i have got a new problem, i can't show this elements in cell
http://i30.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0128/b1/c8224f0960519debf2d142f905a1aeb1.png
i don't not how show the elements of 6 days

Comment: time1.text = [(Lesson *) [[Singleton2 sharedInstance].chetNedel.monday objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] time1];

Comment: but I have a 6 days, not only monday

Comment: the sorting is work, program is run and sorting. But when I add item to array I have error
I doing sort in this method - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
http://i30.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0128/22/d8c7e621392a179742b1e582f96c1922.png
Add Item http://i31.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0128/f2/5ae0d438c9e56f8c3325b05b5a3979f2.jpg
and Error http://i32.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0128/1a/7ec5f058e197e9fec529fac0d789f51a.png
If I not doing sorting, program is good add item., but if I doing sort, I have error on line where add item

Comment: in this case `monday` is an instance of `NSArray`, not `NSMutableArray`; that's why you're getting this error.

Comment: It's a `NSMutableArray` in your definition; but `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` returns a `NSArray` object, so you need to convert it to `NSMutableArray` to add/remove items later. `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:<sorted NSArray>]` will help you.

Comment: It's undesirable to use any language other than English on Stack Overflow. You don't need any other sorting algorithm; you just need to wrap a value returned by `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` in `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:]`.

Comment: написал я допустим функцию сортировки
[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.monday = [[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.monday sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id cont1, id cont2) {
        return [[(Lesson *) cont1 time1] compare:[(Lesson *) cont2 time1]];
    }];
как быть дальше?знания у меня в IOS не большие, учу только месяц

Comment: [Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.monday = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[Singleton sharedInstance].chetNedel.monday sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id cont1, id cont2) { return [[(Lesson *) cont1 time1] compare:[(Lesson *) cont2 time1]]; }]];

Comment: Thank you, you very help me, I write this on rus 2 days ago, but comment disappear

Comment: It was deleted. Please mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Andrey. You stick everything from your arrays in containers and then you sort the containers.
Your container should have as members everything you store in one cell (date, time, text, text2, Englis/mathematic, etc).

And then you sort the cell container array.

```
            cellArr = [cellArr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id cont1, id cont2) {
                // if date in container 1 is earlier than in container 2
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
                // if date is later
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
                // if none of the above
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
            }];
```

Comment: example name of my class is MyClass and name of array is MyArray1, MyArray2, MyArray3,MyArray4,MyArray5. Can woy write me code how it will be look like?

Comment: @Pavel: Please read carefully the answer above. You **need** to create a data container, and only then you can sort all the data in the containers the way you want.

Comment: okey. example my data container MyClass wich have 5 arrays. How will be look like code?

Comment: You don't need a data container with 5 arrays. You need one array with data containers. I've updated my answer.